# Cakephpでデータが二重に保存される

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

環境
　　PHP 5.3.19
　　Cakephp 2.6.1
　　MySQL 5.067

1日1回、別システムから受け取ったCSVファイルを解析し、データベースに登録する処理を書いて運用しています。
処理としては、テーブルのデータを初期化して、全て挿入することにしています。
普段は一意に登録されるのですが、たまにデータが2重に登録される場合があります。
　　※例：5万件のデータを挿入すると、10万件になっている
問題発生時のログを取ってみても、挿入したクエリは全て一意で重複はありませんでした。

原因は何なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

下記に簡易的な処理を書きます。

```
class ConvertCsvController extends AppController {
　　public function exec(){
　　　　//csvからデータ生成
　　　　$class = new hoge1();
　　　　$this->updateToClass($class);

　　　　//csvからデータ生成2
　　　　$class = new hoge2();
　　　　$this->updateToClass($class);
　　}

　　private function updateToClass($class){
　　　　set_time_limit(600);

　　　　//pdoでDBにアクセス（省略
　　　　$pdo = new PDO();　

　　　　//テーブルを初期化
　　　　$pdo->query("TRUNCATE ".$class->TABLE_NAME);

       //トランザクション開始
       $pdo->query("START TRANSACTION");

       try {
　　　　  foreach ( $file as $key => $line ) {
　　　　　  　//内容の生成処理は省略
　　　　  　　//(null,1,2,3,"hoge")みたいなのが出来る
　　　  　　　$values = $line;
　　  　　　　if( !empty( $insert_values ) ){
　  　　　　　　　$insert_values .= ", ";
  　　　　　　}
  　　　　　　$insert_values .= "(". $values . ")";
  　　　　　　$insert_count++;

　　　　　  　if($insert_count > 5000){
　　　　  　　　　$pdo->query($class->INSERT_HEAD.$insert_values);
　　　  　　　　　$insert_values = "";
　　  　　　　　　$insert_count = 0;
　  　　　　　}
  　　　　}
  　　　　//余ったのを入れる
  　　　　if($insert_count > 0){
　　　　　  　$pdo->query($class->INSERT_HEAD.$insert_values);
　　　　  }
         $pdo->query("COMMIT");

       } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $pdo->query("ROLLBACK");
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
       }

　　}
}


//テストクラス、hoge2も同じ形式
class hoge1{
　　public $FILE_PATH = "hoge1.CSV";
　　public $TABLE_NAME = "hoge1";
　　
　　public $INSERT_HEAD = "INSERT INTO `hoge1` (
　　　　`id`, `customer_code`, `spot_code`, `spot_1`, `spot_2`, `place_1`, `place_2`, `center_id`, `center_name`, `business_id`, `business_name`, `create_date`, `update_date`
        ) VALUES ";
}
```

【2015/12/29 追記】
トランザクションを試して様子を見ていましたが問題が再発しました。
　　※レコード内容まではログをとっておらず、insertの発行回数だけ取得していましたが、
　　　5000 * 11で約55000件なのに、レコードは１０万件になっていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テーブルロックでトランザクションを掛けてはいかがでしょうか?
上記ソースだとコンストラクタ、デストラクタに仕掛けるのが手軽に検証できますね。

または、クエリが一意ということで、二重登録になるケースがわかりませんが、
一意であるべきフィールドにユニーク制約を設定しておくのも良いかと思います。

上記で重複エラーになるかどうかを検証すれば、二重にバッチが走っているかもわかると思います。
より原因究明に近づくことでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

確かにトランザクションをかけるべきですね。
初歩的なことなのに忘れてて、恥ずかしい限りですorz
一度トランザクションを掛けて様子を見てみます。

>>または、クエリが一意ということで、二重登録になるケースがわかりませんが、・・・
すいません、説明不足でした。
例えば下記のレコードを1回挿入したとして
>id, code, str
>null, 100, "aaa"

レコードが何故か2つできてしまいます。
>5, 100, "aaa"
>6, 100, "aaa"

Comment: 確認環境で50回、回してテストしました。
問題が出なかったので、本番環境に上げてしばらく様子を見てみます。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 上記コメントいただいた中で、id は自動附番なので、たとえば code にユニーク制約を入れるとエラー箇所がより明確になるのではないでしょうか?

Comment: 単純なユニーク制約は難しそうです。
codeが同じものも複数できるのも正しいので、、、
code2種と作成日でユニーク制約を作れば出来そうですが、再度問題が発生したときに確認してみます。

Comment: 問題が再発したようなので、バッチの多重実行の線は消えました。
次はcodeと作成日で制約作成ですね。

Comment: そうですね、ユニーク制約を試してみます。
ただ、年末ということもあり、本番環境のアップは避けようかと思います。
年明けにアップして様子を見ていきます。
何度も有難うございます。

Comment: 年明けにユニーク制約を試してから、問題なく動作しています。
一旦解決済みとさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました！